# Library with identifier tmplib is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or maybe you don't have read access?)

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using `Legacy free edition of G Suite` account to run my web application. What I want to achieve is to force users to log in. So I deployed the web application with these settings

- `Execute as` **User accessing the web app**
- `Who has access` **Anyone with Google account**

Now I was able to identify the user accessing the web application -  I got their email from `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();` perfect. Then I want to save all their "data" in 'their own' spreadsheet. When I save a file using `DriveApp.createFile(fileName, 'Hello, world!')` the file is save on their Google disc. I want all the application data to be on my disc.

So I created a new project - library - and deployed as library and passed it the email because it will be the file name. It works if I access the web as me - owner of both projects. If I access the web as someone else I got this error `We're sorry, a server error occurred while reading from storage. Error code NOT_FOUND.`

Then I deployed the library as a web application with these settings

- `Execute as` **Me**
- `Who has access` **Anyone** or **Anyone with Google account**

again if I access the web as the owner it works but someone else gets an error `Library with identifier tmplib is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or maybe you don't have read access?)`

Also there is no log. Just error. Actually there are no logs from the library - I used Logger.log() and console.log()

I tried to add the library from the old editor as there was some error reported in past that might cause such error.

Is there any way I can use an web app and library intended way so the file is always saved as me?

**UPDATE**

If I share the library using share button and anyone is `Editor` then the web user needs to give permission to the web application to access their Drive and the file is saved in their Drive. I want ALWAYS the file to be saved in my Drive.

Comment: Have you tried not to use a library at all?

Comment: For example, under your settings of Web Apps, when the library is shared with the users or publicly shared, what result will you obtain?

Comment: @Cooper, if I do not use library a file is saved under the user that is accessing the web. I want it to be saved in my Google disk. I thought I would solve it using a library running as me.

Comment: @Tanaike I tried the lib to share as - `Who has access` **Anyone** or **Anyone with Google account** and the result is the same. The error as in my question. The error happens only for others. The whole script works for me.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Please confirm the settings for Web Apps and library as follows again. 1. At Web Apps, it's `Execute as: User accessing the web app` and `Who has access: Anyone with Google account`. 2. At library, share with the user as the writer (in this case, this user is not owner of the library). And test it again. In my environment, when the library is publicly shared or shared with the user as reader, I confirmed an error occurred. I apologize for this. When the library is shared with the user as the writer, the user can access to Web Apps.

Comment: @Tanaike I do not understand how to ` share library with the user as the writer`. Could you guide me?

Comment: If you mean "share button" then please read my update in the question. Such settings would save the file in web user Drive. Not mine.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, for example, if you are not required to use the library, as a workaround, how about putting the script of library to the Google Apps Script project of Web Apps? Or, how about loading the script using a script? In this case, if the library is the standalone script type, the script becomes a simple.

Comment: Whatever working solution is fine with me. Just I do not understand what you mean by "loading the script using a script". And also ... The library in my question is a  Google Apps Script project deployed as library.. So I am not sure what else I can try. @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. When your library can be used by users and it is the standalone script type, the script can be retrieved using Drive API. So I thought that this might be able to be used. But from `Whatever working solution is fine with me.`, in this case, how about putting the script of library in the GAS project of Web Apps? I thought that this way might be simpler. But, if I misunderstood your situation and your direction, I apologize again.

Comment: I am not sure if getting the script through Drive API would work. I some functions to be run `as me` but the web application runs as `user accessing the web`. I think that file will be saved as `user accessing web` not me.

Comment: I am not Google products guru so I might not understand your point but I thought that I am using GAS project of Web application for the web application itself and actually I tried to deploy the library as Web application too. I cannot see any difference between deploying as library and Web application.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, how about putting the script of library in the GAS project of Web Apps? I thought that this way might be simpler. But, if I misunderstood your situation and your direction, I apologize again.

Comment: hm, I thought that the library IS a GAS project of Wep App. Could you please explain? https://i.imgur.com/kCioZto.png

Answer (score 1):

#### This appears to be a bug!

There is already a report on Google's Issue Tracker which detail the same kind of behaviour:

- [Error when including library](https://issuetracker.google.com/179397312)

You can also hit the ☆ next to the issue number in the top left on the aforementioned pages which lets Google know more people are encountering this and so it is more likely to be seen to faster.

Comment: I commented in the Tracker to see if I am getting the same error.