# How to protect GAS web site with (Google) authentication?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I have working Google Application Script project deployed as Web application. Everything works as desired.

But. I realized that I need to personalized the site for each user. I am using Google spreadsheets as backend data storage solution. I wanted simple but secure way of user authentication. Of course Google came to my mind.

- [Integrating Google Sign-In into your web app](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) seems to me bit to complicated
- because I can use build in features how to deploy the site it self

I am using `Legacy free edition of G Suite account` (I am the admin) to run my web application. So I deployed the web application with these settings

- Execute as User accessing the web app
- Who has access Anyone with Google account

Now I was able to identify the user accessing the web application - I got their email from `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();` perfect. Then I want to save all their "data" in 'their own' spreadsheet. When I save a file using `DriveApp.createFile(fileName, 'Hello, world!')` the file is save on their Google disc. I want all the application data to be on **my disc**.

So I created a new project - library - and deployed as library and passed it the email because it will be the file name. It works if I access the web as me - owner of both projects. If I access the web as someone else I got this error `We're sorry, a server error occurred while reading from storage. Error code NOT_FOUND`. I created another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66215700/library-with-identifier-tmplib-is-missing-perhaps-it-was-deleted-or-maybe-you) for this issue and actually it looks like it is a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/179397312).

Then I deployed the library as a web application with these settings

- Execute as Me
- Who has access Anyone and also I tried Anyone with Google account

I am sure I am not the only one looking for working solution how to create some king of authentication for my GAS web.

Could anyone suggest how you do it on your site?

Comment: Howdy! After studying your question I don't have a clear idea of your goal, could you please clarify it for me? I see that you took different approaches, thought questions and bug reports, which one are you asking about?

Comment: hi @Jacques-GuzelHeron what I want is to force user of my GAS web to login. I am not a profi coder so to do whole login by myself would be time consuming and I guess the result might not be so secure. So I thought I would use an existing solution. I would like my web users to use their Gooogle login to authenticate but I need some functions of my web to be executed as me.

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 ways to authenticate a user on your webApp.

1. Integrate Google-sign-in to your web app **(Recommended)**
2. Execute as User accessing the web app and use `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();` to retrieve the user email **(It works but the users must allow access to their account to use the webApp and GAS projects limit the number of users which can have access)**
3. Make your own login form, validate users usign your own database, and store a token using HTML/Javascript (since GAS does not allow you to create cookies) **(Not recommended, it is not really secure)**

I would recommend to use the Google-sign-in option, but since you said you considered it a bit complicated, then you can use the second option (Execute the app as the user) and for the problem of creating a file on your google disc instead of the user's disc you have 2 options:

1. Create a folder on your google disc and make it public or share it with the accounts using your webApp, then change your code so files are created on your folder.

   `var myFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('123'); myFolder.createFile(fileName, 'Hello, world!');`
2. If you do not want to share the folder, then make it private, create a second webApp which do the read/write files stuff on your folder and then publish it as **executes as me**, then call this second webApp from the first webApp using the `fetch(URL)`; method.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app

Comment: Hi Alfredo, I am not a coder so if I am recommended to use Google Sign in then I will use it. I thought that `executes as me` for the second script that works with files would be much much easier. Oh, I did not think of using `fetch()` to call the second script. Would not is slow down the application.

Comment: Hi Radek, indeed, calling the second webApp using fetch() adds a network latency of around 300ms (not really a problem), but if you considered it slow, you can use the Cache service to make your app faster (developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache). For the login option, I would recommend you to use the second option (the one you have been using) until you get familiar with google-sign-in which can be a little tricky to use within GAS. Hope it helps!

Comment: You helped me a lot. I guess I am bit scared of the `tricky part` of google-sign-in. But also it seems to me that it is the way if the bug for second option is not fixed. Thank you