# How to store cookies or sessions in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am using Google Apps script with a client and want to learn how to store cookies to save login information. I am saving emails and passwords in Google Sheets (yes, the passwords are hashed), but when you login and goto another page, it does not remember your email.

I tried document.cookie but it did not work. Any help?

Comment: The answer to this question may be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66260866/how-to-protect-gas-web-site-with-google-authentication

Comment: You could use PropertiesService or Cache

Comment: Is there a reason for not authenticate via Google? Can you provide more information about your current situation?